# PHP MySQL: Comparar Dados entre Duas Tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas 
**sorteio** e **jogos** num determinado banco Mysql. 
Na tabela sorteio, são armazenados os dados de nº do concurso, 1ª dezena sorteada, 2ª, 3ª, 4ª e 5ª dezena. 
**tabela sorteio**
+------------------------------------------------+
| concurso | so1 | so2 | so3 | so4 | so5 |
+------------------------------------------------+
|. . 3916 ... | 13 ..| 26 ..| 44 ..| 64 ..| 68 ..|
+------------------------------------------------+

Na tabela **jogos**, é armazenada as cartelas jogadas, contendo os dados como nº do concurso do sorteio, 1ª a 5ª dezena marcadas. cada jogo contém um identificado chamado **id_jogos** que é a **P.K** da tabela. 

**tabela jogos**
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
| concurso | id_jogos | jo1 | jo2 | jo3 | jo4 | jo5 |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
|. . 3916 ... | . . 01 . . . | 13 | 28 . | 44 | 68 | 69 .|
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
|. . 3916 ... | . . 02 . . . | 13 | 28 . | 44 | 68 | 69 .|
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
|. . 3917 ... | . . 03 . . . | 13 | 28 . | 44 | 68 | 69 .|
+--------------------------------------------------+-----+

```html
<?php

// Variável recebida referente a consulta
$consulta = $_POST["consulta"];
// variável que conecta ao banco 
$pesquisa = $conn->prepare
    ("SELECT * FROM SORTEIO INNER JOIN JOGOS USING(CONCURSO)");  
$pesquisa->execute();  
$resultado = $pesquisa->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// laço para buscar coluna id_jogos, o valor de cada cartela.
foreach($resultado as $r ){
if ($r['concurso'] == $consulta){
// aqui dentro desse laço quero retornar as dezenas acertadas de cada jogo. exemplo, ao consultar o concurso 3916, encontro três jogos na tabela jogos. são as id_jogos 01 e 02. Na id_jogos 01 há três resultados que se repetem, isso quer dizer que acertei três dezenas. exibo os valores acertados, e passo para o id_jogos 02 realizar outra consulta e exibir os valores acertados. e assim sucessivamente, independente da quantidade de jogos tiver.
}
} 

?>
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Tente se expressar melhor, não está claro o problema.

Comment: Ao explicar as colunas da tabela, coloque nomes específicos das colunas pra gente colocar na resposta, assim fica muito vago. Cole também um pedaço de código pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Nobres amigos @MarcoAurélioDeleu procurei melhorar editando o post para uma melhor entendimento.

Comment: Opa  @EdsonHoracioJunior, editei para melhor compreensão.

Comment: @PedroPaparologia Ok Pedro, agora você explicou o contexto, mas falta explicar qual é o problema/o que você quer.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior , valeu é quase isso, quero retornar de cada jogo as dezenas acertadas individualmente. Ex: As dezenas acertadas do jogo de (id_jogos 01), havendo outro jogo no mesmo concurso exibir ele também separadamente. vamos dizer que num determinado concurso consultado, tenha 10 jogos, quero para cada jogo relacionado na consulta, me retorne as dezenas acertadas.

Comment: @PedroPaparologia o código que eu postei já faz isso, basta você aplicar a sua lógica de visualização agora: exibir em tabela ou divs, se vai ser tudo em uma linha ou separar em linhas, etc, mas a lógica já está correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi é pra exibir as dezenas acertadas de todos os jogos de um determinado concurso, se for o caso você pode filtrar o concurso no SELECT

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM SORTEIO INNER JOIN JOGOS USING(CONCURSO)";
$sql .= "WHERE concurso = {$consulta}";
$conn->prepare($sql);
```

Abaixo está seu código mas agora comparando e exibindo as dezenas acertadas

```
<?php
// Variável recebida referente a consulta
$consulta = $_POST["consulta"];

$sql        = "SELECT * FROM SORTEIO INNER JOIN JOGOS USING(CONCURSO)";
// ou $sql  = "SELECT * FROM SORTEIO INNER JOIN JOGOS USING(CONCURSO)";
//    $sql .= "WHERE concurso = {$consulta}";

// variável que conecta ao banco 
$pesquisa  = $conn->prepare($sql);  
$pesquisa->execute();  
$resultado = $pesquisa->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// laço para buscar coluna id_jogos, o valor de cada cartela.
foreach ($resultado as $r) {

    // este if pode ser removido caso esteja filtrando o concurso no SELECT
    if ($r['concurso'] == $consulta) {            
        $sorteios = array($r['so1'], $r['so2'], $r['so3'], $r['so4'], $r['so5']);
        $jogos    = array($r['jo1'], $r['jo2'], $r['jo3'], $r['jo4'], $r['jo5']);

        // Loop nos jogos
        foreach ($jogos as $jogo) {

            // se jogo foi sorteado, então exibe
            if (in_array($jogo, $sorteios)) {
                echo $jogo;
            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```